# combineLatest refactoring for @deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

The angular material documentation app has the following snippet in it:

```
    // Combine params from all of the path into a single object.
    this.params = combineLatest(
      this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params),
      Object.assign);
```

TSLint strikesout `combineLatest` with this message:

> @deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead

How should that be fixed?

Also if you understand the technique being used, a simple example with elaboration would be awesome.

Here's a code link:

https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-category-list/component-category-list.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```ts
combineLatest(observables, resultSelector)
```

can often be replaced with

```ts
combineLatest(observables).pipe(
  map(resultSelector)
)
```

But whether this works in the same way depends on what parameters your `resultSelector` accepts. `combineLatest(observables)` emits an array and [RxJs automatically spreads this array](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/a331e11696531521ccf0ae62d97b0b8d1f26f28e/src/internal/util/mapOneOrManyArgs.ts#L7) when you're using the deprecated resultSelector.

```ts
return isArray(args) ? fn(...args) : fn(args); // fn is your resultSelector
```

As `Object.assign` returns different values depending on whether you provide an array or multiple values you have to spread the array manually.

```ts
combineLatest(observables).pipe(
  map(items => Object.assign({}, ...items))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The result selector is just a function that can be used to change the shape of the output.

So, you can simply omit the result selector param and use a map to transform the shape:

```
    this.params = combineLatest(
      this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)
    ).pipe(
        map(Object.assign)
    );
```

A common use the of the result selector (for me anyway) was to return the array as an object with named properties, so something like this:

// Old Way

```
myObs$ = combineLatest(
   [src1$, src2$, src3$], 
   ([src1, src2, src3]) => ({src1, src2, src3})
);
```

// New Way

```
myObs$ = combineLatest(src1$, src2$, src3$)
    .pipe(
       map(([src1, src2, src3]) => ({src1, src2, src3}))
    );
```

Comment: I cloned the source and tried it.  It stops rendering.  Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the observable no longer emits?  EDIT: I just saw @fridoo answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

`pipe` the result and use the `map` operator instead, something like:

```js
combineLatest(this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)).pipe(
  map(Object.assign)
);
```

[Reference](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors)

Also, not sure about the intent of the code, since it seems as though it's calling `Object.assign` on a new array reference, not sure why that's necessary, but that's not entirely relevant.

Comment: Yeah ... I did not really understand the intent of `Object.assign` either ... Just looking at the code it seems like they could just do `this.params = this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)` ...

Comment: I added what I think they can just do in the question ... do you see any issues with it?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with all the bits in that library, but using `Object.assign` seems out of place, but perhaps I'm missing some context.