# Combining Angular Path Parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

The Angular Material Docs application combines path parameters like this:

```
    // Combine params from all of the path into a single object.
    this.params = combineLatest(
        this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params), Object.assign);
```

Here's an example:
https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-category-list/component-category-list.ts

However this produces the error:

> @deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead

So to get around that it's possible to do this:

```
    this.params = combineLatest(
      this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)
    ).pipe(
        map(Object.assign)
    );
```

As documented here:
[combineLatest refactoring for @deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235967/combinelatest-refactoring-for-deprecated-resultselector-no-longer-supported)

However that produces this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> at SafeSubscriber._next (component-category-list.ts:50)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
> at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
> at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
> at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:73)
> at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
> at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
> at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
> at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
> at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
> at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)

So it looks as if the `section` URL parameter that the component is looking for is no longer being captured after the refactoring.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters must be destructured when passing to `Object.assign` like this:

```
    // Combine params from all of the path into a single object.
    this.params = combineLatest(
      this._route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)).
      pipe(map((params:Params[])=>Object.assign({}, ...params)));
```