# Error with combineLatest after updating rxjs from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, version, combinelatest

After updating rxjs from version 6.6.6 to 7.4.0 I got an error in my combineLatest function.

```
searchQuery = new FormControl(null);
searchStatus = new FormControl<UserStatus>('ALL');

searchParams$ = combineLatest(
  this.searchQuery.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null), debounceTime(200)),
  this.searchStatus.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('ALL')),
  (query: string, status: string) => {
    return { query, status };
  }
);
```

this is the error message

No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '(query: string, status: string) => { query: string; status: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SchedulerLike'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [combineLatest refactoring for @deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235967/combinelatest-refactoring-for-deprecated-resultselector-no-longer-supported)

Answer (score 1):

The function signature of `combineLatest` has changed to:

```js
export function combineLatest<A extends readonly unknown[]>(sources: readonly [...ObservableInputTuple<A>]): Observable<A>;
```

Your new code should look something like this:

```js
searchParams$ = combineLatest([
    this.searchQuery.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null), debounceTime(200)),
    this.searchStatus.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('ALL')),
])
    .pipe(
        map(([query, status]: [string | null, string | null]) => {
            return { query, status };
        }));
```